# Car registered in MD, stored in MD, but I live out of state

Tags: united-states

I lived in MD a year ago, own a car that's registered in MD, but now I live out of state.  It's a utility van I am converting into an RV to go on a long road trip next year, and it's currently in storage in MD as I work on it when I'm back there.

I currently live in Hawaii but will be returning to the mainland next summer.

It has valid tags, and is insured with a MD company.  To complicate things, when I registered the van I had a DC license and a MD address, none of which I have anymore.

Any advice on how to renew registration?  MVA clearly states that vehicle registrations will NOT get forwarded by USPS, and when I try to change my address using my Driver's License Number (both the Hawaii license, my old DC license, and even my OLD MD license) it fails to accept the number.

I'll probably call MVA but figured maybe someone has experience...

Thanks!

Comment: "It has valid tags, "  Was this still true after you moved out-of-state?